# Why it returns 0 results even if where clause has matches

Tags: mysql

I'm facing a very weird problem:

I have two tables (and only two tables) in my MySql database, this is how they look like:
[image]
[image]

[image: select * from records]
[image: select * from user_profile]

As you can see, both table has an entry with the same user_id: 00000c289a1829a808ac09c00daf10bc3c4e223b

The problem is, if I execute

```
select * from records where user_id = "00000c289a1829a808ac09c00daf10bc3c4e223b"
```

database does return a result with 0 rows, while the same where clause will return one row correctly on user_profile table.

Any idea?

Comment: Check your 'user_id' column record. In first table it is with "" and in second table it has simple text without "". So may be possible your query got wrong and display 0 result while for others it match perfectly and display one row.

Comment: there are quotes around values in user_id field.. wats that..?

Comment: @vijayrami Ah! Thanks~~ T_T

Answer (score 1):

As @vijayrami pointed out, it's `""`.